# Return from json_encode fails

Tags: php, json, jssor

I have the jssor slider installed and working. I am trying to add the ability to change the slide type from an external file using php. In my unedited jssor code, if I enter the following as the slide types, they work as expected:

```
    {$Duration:800,$Opacity:2},
    {$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}
```

When I try to load from a function, as illustrated in the code below, the output of the console command is

```
    0: "{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2},"​
    1: "{$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}"
```

If I strip off the quotes and place those in the _SlideshowTransitions function they work. So is it the quotes that are causing a problem? If so, how can I remove those? Or is it that the jssor function won't work with a variable? Or something else?

```
    function GetTransitions() {
        $xsisitons = array();
        $xsisitons[] = '{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2},';
        $xsisitons[] = '{$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}';
        return json_encode($xsisitons);
    }
    $jsondata = GetTransitions(); 

    <script>
    var xsitions = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>;
    console.dir(xsitions);

    var _SlideshowTransitions = [
      xsitions
    ];
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't know jssor, but you are building what looks like JSON strings and then JSON encoding them.  Maybe `$xsisitons[] = [$Duration=>800,$Opacity=>2];` etc. then encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create the JS directly:

```
<?php
    function GetTransitions() {
        return $rawJS = '[
            {
                $Duration: 800,
                $Opacity: 2
            },
            {
                $Duration: 1000,
                y: 1,
                $Easing: $Jease$.$InBounce,
                $Opacity: 2
            }
        ]';
    }
    $options = GetTransitions(); 
?>
    <script>
    var xsitions = <?php echo $options; ?>;
    console.dir(xsitions);

    var _SlideshowTransitions = xsitions;
    </script>
```

This is the line that prevents you from using `json_encode`:

```
$Easing: $Jease$.$InBounce,
```

`json_encode` would treat `$Jease$.$InBounce` as a string rather than JS code, preventing it from functioning as expected.

That makes `GetTransitions` extremely dangerous, which is hinted at by the new variable name `rawJS`. Make sure you pay attention to what that function outputs.

You could safely make `$Duration`, `$Opacity`, and `y` dynamic in the PHP by casting input variables to int when building the `$rawJS` string, or by escaping the dynamic values (but not the whole string) with `json_encode`:

```
function GetTransitions($duration_1, $duration_2, $opacity, $y) {
    return $rawJS = '[
        {
            $Duration: ' . (int)$duration_1 . ',
            $Opacity: ' . (int)$opacity . '
        },
        {
            $Duration: ' . (int)$duration_2 . ',
            y: ' . (int)$y . ',
            $Easing: $Jease$.$InBounce,
            $Opacity: ' . (int)$opacity . '
        }
    ]';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and the safety suggestion. The code failed with an error but I noticed you changed _SlideshowTransitions = [ xsitions; ] to _SlideshowTransitions = xsitions; so I tried that with the original code and it worked! I've been fiddling with this for a month so I really appreciate the fix, intentional or not. :) Thank you.

Comment: That was an intentional change. The brackets (indicating an array) are part of the $rawJS string in the sample code I provided. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

What you want isn't correct json, so `json_encode` wouldn't help you. But instead, you could build the js string on your own.

```
$xsisitons[] = '{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}';
$xsisitons[] = '{$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}';
return '[' . join(',', $xsisitons) . ']';
```

Comment: I tried your code. It changed the console output to the following but the slider still ignores the types: 0: Object { "$Duration": 800, "$Opacity": 2 }
​
1: Object { "$Duration": 1000, y: 1, "$Opacity": 2, … }